# Reordering ng-repeat after editing an element

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have an row `ng-repeat` with `orderBy` at a certain property/column say `name`. If I edit a column, it redirects into another page with the fields as editable input. When I edit `name` and commit the edit, it goes back to the table page, but the edited element stays at the previous position when it should have moved somewhere. So how do I make AngularJS compute orderBy again? Thanks.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: probably you need to insert `$scope.$apply()` after your edit code.

Comment: If he is completely working under angularjs, he does not need $apply()

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something wrong. [Here's a working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azOMRO) (click on a person to edit their age).

And here's some code needed to post my answer with a link to codepen:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'age'">...</div>
```

Comment: I wonder why it's working with you but not with mine. Is it because I'm using old version 1.1.5? I can't upgrade though because my app is a Hawtio plugin (which unfortunately has an AngularJS lib stuck to v1.1.5).

Comment: Nope. I've changed the version used in the linked demo to 1.1.5 and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your view you can do it this way:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in sortedItems = (allItems | orderBy : itemProperty : reverse)" >
</div>
```

2. If you want to to do it from your controller( you have to remove filter from the example above):

```js
$scope.$watch('sortedItems', function() {
        $scope.allItems = orderBy($scope.allItems, itemProperty, reverse);
    }, true);
```

The second option will do the job for you, but is definitely not a good practice, and you should avoid it if possible.

Comment: I didn't use reverse as I want the ordering straightforward. Is it okay if there's no reverse?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I didn't realize `reverse` is just a boolean.